# How to compare two values in one associate array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare two prices within an associative array. I need to pull both prices out so that I can make a calculation. The array I have is:

```
[10] => Array
    (
        [A Is For Annabelle 681 2 (fat Quarter)] => 2.8500
        [A Is For Annabelle 681 2 (yardage)] => 7.9500
    )
```

And the code i'm trying is:

```
$fqPrice;
$ydPrice;

foreach ($value as $key => $value) {

    if (strpos($key, 'yd') !== false || strpos($key, 'yardage') !== false ) {
              $ydPrice = $value;
     }

     if (strpos($key, 'fq') !== false || strpos($key, 'fat quarter') !== false ) {
              $fqPrice = $value;
     }
}
```

It gets to the first if statement but doesn't execute the second one.

Comment: missing some code, and not sure what the question is. you dont say if the code your trying works or not

Comment: @Dagon sorry about that, updated it

Comment: you have one more dimension than your looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding the extra array dimension loop (you probably already have this), i changed to a `preg_match` which is 'cleaner':

```
<?php
$value = array(10=>array('A Is For Annabelle 681 2 (fat Quarter)'=>'2.8500','A Is For Annabelle 681 2 (yardage)'=>'7.9500'));

$ydPrice=$fqPrice='';


foreach ($value as $first){

    foreach ($first as $key=>$value){


        if (preg_match('#yd|yardage#',$key)){
            $ydPrice = $value;
        }

        if (preg_match('#fq|fat Quarter#',$key)){
            $fqPrice = $value;
        }
    }
}

echo 'y=' . $ydPrice;
echo 'f=' . $fqPrice;
?>
```

demo: http://ideone.com/JTJNWx

if your only interest in `$value[10]`, you can just use `foreach($value[10] as $key=>$value){}`

Answer (score 1):

well, your second one IS being executed, but it returns `false` on both expressions; so it means the `$value` will not be assigned to `$fqPrice`.

You need to remember that `strpos()` is *case-sensitive*, you can either change to use `strpos($key, 'fat Quarter')` or use the `stripos` function instead.